# Telegraf - inputs.procstat procstat Plugin - Using command line pattern or username

Tags: pattern-matching, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-plugins

Using: **Telegraf v1.0.1** or later

Telegraf procstat plugin's documentation:
https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/procstat

Under **Documentation**, it says:

*The procstat plugin can be used to monitor system resource usage by an individual process using their /proc data.*

*The plugin will tag processes by their PID and their process name.*

*Processes can be specified either by pid file, by executable name, by command line pattern matching, or by username (in this order or priority. Procstat plugin will use pgrep when executable name is provided to obtain the pid.*

My custom config File:
 **/etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/my_custom_process_service-telegraf.conf** contains:

```
[[inputs.procstat]]
  exe = "."
  prefix = "service_process"

[[inputs.procstat]]
  pid_file = "/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid"
  prefix = "service_process"
```

The above configuration works fine per the syntax.

**Question:**

The documentation says about using `exe`, `pid_file`, but it doesn't give an example on how to use the `command line pattern matching` OR by `username`. Can I get some examples if you know how to use it?

Comment: It was not in the README but i looked into the source files and it's mentioned there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this info in the source file: https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/inputs/procstat/procstat.go (under variable `var sampleConfig =`

```
  ## Must specify one of: pid_file, exe, or pattern
  ## PID file to monitor process
  pid_file = "/var/run/nginx.pid"

  ## executable name (ie, pgrep <exe>)
  # exe = "nginx"
  ## pattern as argument for pgrep (ie, pgrep -f <pattern>)

  # pattern = "nginx"
  ## user as argument for pgrep (ie, pgrep -u <user>)
  # user = "nginx"

  ## override for process_name
  ## This is optional; default is sourced from /proc/<pid>/status
  # process_name = "bar"

  ## Field name prefix
  prefix = ""


  ## comment this out if you want raw cpu_time stats
  fielddrop = ["cpu_time_*"]

  ## This is optional; moves pid into a tag instead of a field
  pid_tag = false
```